# How to query subclasses of Page in wagtail?

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

In home page and search page, I'd like to list all kinds of pages with different detailed display. I wrote the code below following the document:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from my.models import ArticlePage, GalleryPage, VideoPage, SharedLinkPage


PAGE_TYPES = (ArticlePage, GalleryPage, VideoPage, SharedLinkPage,)


class HomePage(Page):
    subpage_types = list(PAGE_TYPES)

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(HomePage, self).get_context(request)
        context['posts'] = Page.objects.type(PAGE_TYPES).live()
        context['recent_posts'] = Page.objects.type(PAGE_TYPES).live()
        return context
```

In this case, I can only get `[<Page: 1>, <Page:2>]`, what I really want is `[<ArticlePage: 1>, <GalleryPage:2>]`.

My question is the same in search page but with `search` query:

```
Page.search('something', ArticlePage)
```

Would be better:

```
search_backend.search('something').types(PAGE_TYPES).live()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `specific` attribute to get the most specific subclassed form of each page:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.wagtailcore.models.Page.specific

Also, there's a `specific()` method on `PageQuerySet` which can also be called to retrieve the specific version of all Pages in that queryset.

Finally, notice that calling `specific` on a page or queryset will result to an extra query so try to group all `specific` calls together. For example, instead of doing:

```
for page in pages:
    specific_page = page.specific # This will result to N extra queries (!)
    # do something with specific_page
```

do a

```
for specigic_page in pages.specific(): # 1 extra query for each page subclass
    # do something with specific_page
```

Comment: Just a tiny correction - the PageQuerySet version of `specific` will perform one extra query for each distinct page type that exists in the queryset. Your point still stands though - it's still much better than calling `specific` on each page individually.

Comment: @gasman correct it will need to do a join to bring the extra info from each subpage table. I've edited the answer a little to reflect that.